# python errors in Apple TensorFlow on M1 (apple silicon)

Tags: python, tensorflow, apple-m1, macos-big-sur

Running on a M1 mac mini under Big Sur, most current version.

Following the current Apple docs to install tensorflow in a virtual environment I created called "apple_tensorflow". Apple docs here:
https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Am getting the following errors - how can I fix?

```
(apple_tensorflow) GR@mysys ~ % python
Python 3.8.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 25 2021, 22:55:00) 
[Clang 11.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apple_tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 449, in <module>
    _ll.load_library(_plugin_dir)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apple_tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 155, in load_library
    py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apple_tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow-plugins/libmetal_plugin.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MPSGraphCompilationDescriptor
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apple_tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow-plugins/libmetal_plugin.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 12.0)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph.framework/Versions/A/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph

>>>
```

All required dependencies are correctly installed. Same errors exist when I try from a jupyter notebook.

Thanks in advance for any help, suggestions or input.

Comment: have you tried typing `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` in the terminal?

Comment: or just `pip install tensorflow` may work too

Comment: you may need to replace `tensorflow` with `apple_tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

I also go this error when following Apple's tensor flow instructions this morning (Feb 9, 2022). I am also on Big Sur. Something I missed is the Apple doc we followed is for the new PluggableDevices version of Tensorflow and Apple only supports this with MacOS 12.1 and up.

PluggableDevices prevents TensorFlow devs from having to modify the core of TensorFlow every time a new company comes out with new hardware, like Apple's M1.

Because we are still on Big Sur we will have to use the alpha version of tensorflow-macos.

I'm not ready to upgrade to the new version of MacOS so I installed Miniforge3, created a Python 3.8 environment (as required by tf macos alpha) with conda and installed using the Alpha instructions on the github page:

([https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/153])

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwidjaja1/DSOnMacARM/main/environment.yml

conda env create --file=./environment.yml --name=tensorflow

conda activate tensorflow

pip install --upgrade --force --no-dependencies https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/download/v0.1alpha3/tensorflow_addons_macos-0.1a3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
```

And then I ran the MINST test program...

```
python ./test-minst.py
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 351us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1062
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 350us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1045
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 358us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1050
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 358us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1070
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 359us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1069
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 349us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1068
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 348us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1049
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 360us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1038
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 350us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1056
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 1s 348us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1073
```